# How to improve the use of multiple retrofit calls to an api web service?

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, retrofit

I have been working in a small project to load data from a database and show it in different listviews trough an api web service.

In this moment I'm using the following approach. 
To fill one list I make a retrofit call and then pass it to the Adapter to show the data. Then make the next call to fill different list then another until all list are filled.

[image]

Is there any better way to do this?

To exemplify my question I will use a dummy functional code.

My Fragment class where I send the resquest is:

```
public class FragmentDummy extends Fragment {

final private String myURL = "myURL";

private ListView listOne;
private ListView listTwo;
private ListView listThree;

private void initViews(View view) {
    listOne = view.findViewById(R.id.lv_first);
    listTwo = view.findViewById(R.id.lv_second);
    listThree = view.findViewById(R.id.lv_third);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_dummy_layout, container, false);
    initViews(view);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
    super.onActivityCreated(state);
    FillListOne();
}


private List<ManagerList> listResponse = new ArrayList<>();

private void FillListOne() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(myURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ServiceList listInfo = retrofit.create(ServiceList.class);
    Call<List<ManagerList>> listRequest = listInfo.getListOne();

    listRequest.enqueue(new Callback<List<ManagerList>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ManagerList>> call, 
   Response<List<ManagerList>> response) {

            listResponse = response.body();

            AdapterList adapterListOne = new AdapterList(getContext(), 
        listResponse);
            listOne.setAdapter(adapterListOne);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ManagerList>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

private void FillListTwo() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(myURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ServiceList listInfo = retrofit.create(ServiceList.class);
    Call<List<ManagerList>> listRequest = listInfo.getListTwo();

    listRequest.enqueue(new Callback<List<ManagerList>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ManagerList>> call, 
    Response<List<ManagerList>> response) {

            listResponse = response.body();

            AdapterList adapterListTwo = new AdapterList(getContext(), 
        listResponse);
            listTwo.setAdapter(adapterListTwo);

            FillListThree();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ManagerList>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

private void FillListThree() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(myURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ServiceList listInfo = retrofit.create(ServiceList.class);
    Call<List<ManagerList>> listRequest = listInfo.getListThree();

    listRequest.enqueue(new Callback<List<ManagerList>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ManagerList>> call, Response<List<ManagerList>> response) {

            listResponse = response.body();

            AdapterList adapterListThree = new AdapterList(getContext(), listResponse);
            listThree.setAdapter(adapterListThree);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ManagerList>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}


 }
```

My interface class:

```
public interface ServiceList {


@GET("api/listOne")
Call<List<ManagerList>> getListOne();

@GET("api/listTwo")
Call<List<ManagerList>> getListTwo();

@GET("api/listTree")
Call<List<ManagerList>> getListThree();

}
```

ManagerList class is where I define structure of the object.

AdapterList class is the class to fill the ListView.

My xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
tools:context=".FragmentDummy">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_firstTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="First List"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/steelblue"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title_size"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/info_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_secondTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Second List"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/steelblue"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title_size"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_second"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/info_size" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_thirdTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Third List"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/steelblue"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title_size"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_third"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/info_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have read that using Rx Java this can be improved and optimizied, however the topic is huge and I dont know where to start to improve my code.

I know I can use ReciclerView instead of ListView but is just to exemplify the service calls.

Comment: Why are you waiting for one call to be finished to start the next? You can start loading data for all three lists at the same time.

Comment: In my little example I dont show it, but I do this because at the end of the calls I send all the information to the adapter to show the information at the same time. I thougth It would be easier to explain my question.